# at sign @ with Imperavi Redactor wysiwyg editor

Tags: shortcut, redactor, at-sign

i try to add an **@ sign** in a text using Redactor JS but it seems to be a shortcut key so it dont work for me, nothing appears.
I can type it in the "code mode" but not in the "editor mode"
Do you have an idea for overriding this bug ?

I'm french so i use ALT Gr + 0 , which is also the key for the à and @

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

**Problem fixed :**

this problem is from shortcuts key ALT Gr + 0

I find the line 1766 in the redactor.js and i bypass the condition by adding RETURN to avoid the e.preventDefault() which is **blocking my @**.

replace :

if (key === 48) this.shortcutsLoadFormat(e, 'p'); // ctrl + alt + 0

by :

if (key === 48) return;